# Postfix randmap in transport maps

Tags: postfix

I have a use case on a test server (postfix 3.3) configured with virtual domains where I want to fail (bounce) a percentage of the inbound emails for each of my virtual domains. Using a single host, is it possible to use a feature like "randmap" as part of my transport db?  For example, my hashed transport file looks like this now:

domain1.com   :

domain2.com   :

and I would like to implement something like this:

domain1.com  randmap:{:,:,error:error msg1,error:error msg2}

domain2.com  randmap:{:,:,error:error msg3,error:error msg4}

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Why are you thinking of `transport`? This sounds more like something best placed in  `smtpd_sender_restrictions` or `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` (depending on how you want to treat multi-recipient deliveries).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  In transport, I'm able to easily map a specific domain to any error message and it generates the bounce records I'm looking for perfectly.  I didn't want to limit it to a specific domain(s) however, I wanted to generated a percentage of bounces across all domains. (I'm downstream from an ESP and I am generating data to populate email marketing reporting.)  Not sure if it is restrictions I am looking for.